# How to get string from parenthesis using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

i want to retrieve the string from parenthesis. Following is the text

> Kaminey  **(English: (The) (Sc)oundrels()hggg)**
>   asd **(sa)** dsad is a 2009 Indian caper thriller film directed by
>   Vishal Bhardwaj and featuring Shahid Kapoor, Priyanka Chopra and Amol
>   Gupte in the lead **(roles)**. Set against the backdrop of the Mumbai
>   underworld, Kaminey follows a rivalry between a pair of twins, one
>   with a lisp and the other with a stutter, over the course of a single
>   day..

Now from this text i want to get three strings

> 1. (English: (The) (Sc)oundrels()hggg)
> 2. (sa)
> 3. (roles)

I had tried following regular expression for this

> re.compile(r'\(.*?\)')
>
> re.compile(r'/\(([^)]+)\)/')

Comment: And what have you tried to do so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a regex-writing service

Comment: we cannot find regrex from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would match the parenthesis which has the depth of 1.

```
>>> example = 'My email is John@gmail.com. My name is John. Her email is Anna@gmail.com .I am sam'
>>> s = '''Kaminey (English: (The) (Sc)oundrels()hggg) asd (sa) dsad is a 2009 Indian caper thriller film directed by Vishal Bhardwaj and featuring Shahid Kapoor, Priyanka Chopra and Amol Gupte in the lead (roles). Set against the backdrop of the Mumbai underworld, Kaminey follows a rivalry between a pair of twins, one with a lisp and the other with a stutter, over the course of a single day..'''
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\((?:\([^()]*\)|[^()])*\)', s)
['(English: (The) (Sc)oundrels()hggg)', '(sa)', '(roles)']
```